# Definition of a limit on logarithms

Tags: calculus

Use the definition if the limit to prove that  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \log_9 (81n^2 +1) -\log_3 n =2$.

Not sure how to dimplify and make a delta episolon proof.

Answer (score 1):

Start by seeing that $\log_3 n = \log_9 n^2$. So you have to calculate the limit of
$$
\log_9(81n^2+1) - \log_9(n^2) = \log_9\frac{81n^2+1}{n^2} = log_9(81+\frac{1}{n^2})
$$